# file uploads returning wrong file size on files over 4g

Tags: php, upload

hi guys i have a file upload system for some large files and when i upload a file that's over 4gig it returns the file size with a -2323223 is there a way to fix this its just a basic form for now so im assuming its a php config somewhere or a limitation on and files under 4 gig it returns the size correctly

```
<form method="POST" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file">
<input type="submit">
</form>

echo $_FILES["file"]["size"];
```

Comment: it's a well documented limit of 32 bit integers

Comment: best solution to move to 64 bit integers on windows ?

Comment: no idea, never used PHP on windows slice.

Answer (score 1):

32bit integer can address only as much. You need more bits to address bytes past the 4GB point, a number bigger than 32bit, logically it would be 64bit.

In order to make it work you'll need to run **64bit PHP on a 64bit CPU with 64bit operating system**, then you will be able to address files as large as 1.024 Petabytes.

> The size of an integer is platform-dependent, although a maximum value of about two billion is the usual value (that's 32 bits signed). 64-bit platforms usually have a maximum value of about 9E18, **except for Windows, which is always 32 bit**. PHP does not support unsigned integers. Integer size can be determined using the constant PHP_INT_SIZE, and maximum value using the constant PHP_INT_MAX since PHP 4.4.0 and PHP 5.0.5.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php

Answer (score -1):

Get the path of the uploaded file and use the following function to get it's size:

```
<?php
  /**
   * Get the size of file, platform- and architecture-independant.
   * This function supports 32bit and 64bit architectures and works fith large files > 2 GB
   * The return value type depends on platform/architecture: (float) when PHP_INT_SIZE < 8 or (int) otherwise
   * @param   resource $fp
   * @return  mixed (int|float) File size on success or (bool) FALSE on error
   */
  function my_filesize($fp) {
    $return = false;
    if (is_resource($fp)) {
      if (PHP_INT_SIZE < 8) {
        // 32bit
        if (0 === fseek($fp, 0, SEEK_END)) {
          $return = 0.0;
          $step = 0x7FFFFFFF;
          while ($step > 0) {
            if (0 === fseek($fp, - $step, SEEK_CUR)) {
              $return += floatval($step);
            } else {
              $step >>= 1;
            }
          }
        }
      } elseif (0 === fseek($fp, 0, SEEK_END)) {
        // 64bit
        $return = ftell($fp);
      }
    }
    return $return;
  }
?>
```

SRC: http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php#115792

Comment: doesn't really address the users issue.

Comment: 64bit windows, 32bit PHP, file provided is 51GB. The condition is not met at `if (0 === fseek($fp, 0, SEEK_END))` (in 32bit part) and there isn't `else`, therefore script ends.

Comment: @r3wt I think Pedro meant that the script can be used after upload to check the actual size. The asker never said the upload itself went wrong, just the reported size was wrong.